# 2 horizontal lines around title css

Tags: css, html

Im using the code below to make a horizontal line surround my tittle. But can someone help me make it two lines?  http://jsfiddle.net/7jGHS/

```
<h2><span>THIS IS A TEST</span></h2>
```

```css
h2 { width:100%; text-align:center; border-bottom: 1px solid #000; line-height:0.1em; margin:10px 0 20px; } 
h2 span { background:#fff; padding:0 10px; }
```

Comment: You mean a double line instead of single??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `border-top: 1px solid #000;` to `h2`. This way, it will have two perfectly centerised lines next to your `h2`. Using `border-bottom-style:double;` will make them off center, and more towards the bottom of the element which looks very uneven.

[**FIDDLE DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7jGHS/1047/)

[**FULL SCREEN DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7jGHS/1047/show/)

Updated CSS:

```
h2 {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    line-height:0.1em;
    margin:10px 0 20px;
}
h2 span {
    background:#fff;
    padding:0 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply Add

```
border-bottom-style:double;
```

Here is the code and **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7jGHS/1049/)**

```
h2 {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    border-bottom-style:double;
    line-height:0.1em;
    margin:10px 0 20px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
h2 span {
    background:#fff;
    padding:0 10px;
}
```

***OR***

```
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
```

Here is code And **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7jGHS/1051/)**

```
h2 {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    line-height:0.1em;
    margin:10px 0 20px;

}
h2 span {
    background:#fff;
    padding:0 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add

```
border-top: 1px solid #000;
```

to h2 tag in css
.

```
h2 { 
     width:100%; 
     text-align:center;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #000; 
     line-height:0.1em; 
     margin:10px 0 20px; 
     border-top: 1px solid #000; //added only this line
    }
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vY6EP/)

Answer (score 1):

just add **border-top: 1px solid #000;** to h2 tag

Answer (score 1):

I have Updated your fiddle [Check Here](http://jsfiddle.net/7jGHS/1052/)

```
    h2 { width:100%; 
text-align:center; 
border-bottom: 1px solid #000; 
border-top: 1px solid #000;
line-height:0.1em;
 margin:10px 0 20px; } 
    h2 span { background:#fff; 
padding:0 10px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

there is always the option to use a background image for the line surrounding the title.
Same as above answers adding:
    `background-image:url(image.png)`
both to the `h1` and `h1 span` styling.